# Error with my trigger. What should I do?

Tags: oracle

This trigger fails when it's called:

```
create or replace TRIGGER UNIQUE_PHYSICIAN_TRG 
    BEFORE INSERT ON UNIQUE_PHYSICIAN 
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
      <<COLUMN_SEQUENCES>>
      BEGIN
        IF INSERTING AND :NEW.UNIQUE_ID IS NULL THEN
          SELECT UNIQUE_PHYSICIAN_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.UNIQUE_ID FROM SYS.DUAL;
        END IF;
        IF INSERTING AND :NEW.FSA IS NULL THEN
          SELECT SUBSTRING(inserted.POSTAL_CODE, 0, 3) INTO :NEW.FSA FROM INSERTED;
    END IF;
      END COLUMN_SEQUENCES;
    END;
```

The line:

```
  SELECT SUBSTRING(inserted.POSTAL_CODE, 0, 3) INTO :NEW.FSA FROM INSERTED;
```

seems to be the root of the problem. Is something wrong syntactically?

Comment: Side note : `IF INSERTING` is absolute redundant in this case. The trigger as it is fires only on inserts.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle doesn't have an `inserted` (or a `deleted` or an `updated`) table.  That's something that SQL Server provides in a trigger.  The Oracle substring function is also `substr` not `substring`.

My guess is that you just want

```
IF :new.fsa IS NULL
THEN
  :new.fsa := SUBSTR(:new.POSTAL_CODE, 0, 3);
END IF;
```